# Android Studio se cierra al querer abrir un layout

Tags: android-studio

Instalé la última versión de Android Studio en Windows 10 y al intentar abrir un layout se cierra por completo Android Studio. He buscado una solución en Internet pero no he podido encontrar una solución. Cada vez que falla, recibo un informe de error de texto, no sé cómo interpretar toda esta información, ¿podrían ser tan amable para ayudarme a resolver esto?.

Informe de error de texto

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
> EXCEPTION_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION (0xc000001d) at pc=0x00007ff8bd2039af, pid=3032, tid=3188
> JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (11.0.10) (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
> Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.10+0-b96-7249189, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
> Problematic frame:
> C  [libandroid_runtime.dll+0xb39af]

No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
See problematic frame for where to report the bug.

CAPTURA DE UNOS SEGUNDOS ANTES DE CERRARSE POR COMPLETO ANDROID STUDIO
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Jony es como si se quedara sin memoria, igualmente me choca este mensage: "JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (11.0.10)" tienes instalado las ultimas versiones de JDK y JRE ? lo puedes instalar desde el android studio.

Comment: Hola ante todo gracias por comentar, si tengo todo instalado a la ultima versiones y el problema sigue. La verdad que nunca tuve un incoveniente parecido con las anteriores versiones.